# Tensorflow metal causes NSE exception

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently running tensorflow-macos v2.12.0 on my Mac M1 with macOS Monterey 12.2,set up in a python virtual environment with Python 3.11.0, I am able to train any model on CPU without error and without using tensorflow-metal. But when I try to leverage GPU by installing tensorflow-metal it crashes with this error

```
2023-06-20 20:59:55.145 Python[5953:181520] -[MPSGraphCompilationDescriptor setOptimizationLevel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16da9a010
2023-06-20 20:59:55.169 Python[5953:181520] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MPSGraphCompilationDescriptor setOptimizationLevel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16da9a010'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001af9c41cc __exceptionPreprocess + 240
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001af7157b8 objc_exception_throw + 60
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001afa571a0 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001af924360 ___forwarding___ + 1728
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001af923be0 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
        5   libmetal_plugin.dylib               0x0000000148262cd4 ___ZN12metal_plugin11runMPSGraphEP11MetalStreamP8MPSGraphP12NSDictionaryS5__block_invoke + 112
        6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001af6babac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001af6c9e00 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
        8   libmetal_plugin.dylib               0x0000000148262c50 _ZN12metal_plugin11runMPSGraphEP11MetalStreamP8MPSGraphP12NSDictionaryS5_ + 108
        9   libmetal_plugin.dylib               0x0000000148086db8 _ZN12metal_plugin16MetalBinaryGraph7ComputeEPNS_15OpKernelContextERKNS_6TensorES5_S5_ + 1488
        10  libmetal_plugin.dylib               0x00000001480930c0 _ZN12metal_plugin15MPSBinaryOpBaseIbbE7ComputeEPNS_15OpKernelContextE + 940
        11  libmetal_plugin.dylib               0x0000000148092ac8 _ZN12metal_pluginL16BinaryOp_ComputeINS_13MPSLogicalAndIbbEEbEEvPvP18TF_OpKernelContext + 52
        12  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x00000001070f79f8 _ZN10tensorflow15PluggableDevice7ComputeEPNS_8OpKernelEPNS_15OpKernelContextE + 148
        13  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x000000010703c1c0 _ZN10tensorflow12_GLOBAL__N_126SingleThreadedExecutorImpl3RunERKNS_8Executor4ArgsE + 2100
        14  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x0000000107006a28 _ZN10tensorflow26FunctionLibraryRuntimeImpl7RunSyncENS_22FunctionLibraryRuntime7OptionsEyN4absl12lts_202301254SpanIKNS_6TensorEEEPNSt3__16vectorIS6_NS9_9allocatorIS6_EEEE + 420
        15  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x00000001070103b0 _ZNK10tensorflow29ProcessFunctionLibraryRuntime18RunMultiDeviceSyncERKNS_22FunctionLibraryRuntime7OptionsEyPNSt3__16vectorINS5_7variantIJNS_6TensorENS_11TensorShapeEEEENS5_9allocatorISA_EEEENS5_8functionIFN4absl12lts_202301256StatusERKNS0_21ComponentFunctionDataEPNS0_12InternalArgsEEEE + 1336
        16  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x00000001070155ec _ZNK10tensorflow29ProcessFunctionLibraryRuntime7RunSyncERKNS_22FunctionLibraryRuntime7OptionsEyN4absl12lts_202301254SpanIKNS_6TensorEEEPNSt3__16vectorIS8_NSB_9allocatorIS8_EEEE + 848
        17  libtensorflow_cc.2.dylib            0x00000002a0b878ec _ZN10tensorflow19KernelAndDeviceFunc3RunEPNS_19ScopedStepContainerERKNS_15EagerKernelArgsEPNSt3__16vectorINS6_7variantIJNS_6TensorENS_11TensorShapeEEEENS6_9allocatorISB_EEEEPN3tsl19CancellationManagerERKNS6_8optionalINS_19EagerFunctionParamsEEERKNSJ_INS_17ManagedStackTraceEEEPNSG_24CoordinationServiceAgentE + 572
        18  libtensorflow_cc.2.dylib            0x00000002a0b38118 _ZN10tensorflow18EagerKernelExecuteEPNS_12EagerContextERKN4absl12lts_2023012513InlinedVectorIPNS_12TensorHandleELm4ENSt3__19allocatorIS6_EEEERKNS7_8optionalINS_19EagerFunctionParamsEEERKN3tsl4core11RefCountPtrINS_15KernelAndDeviceEEEPNS_14GraphCollectorEPNSI_19CancellationManagerENS3_4SpanIS6_EERKNSD_INS_17ManagedStackTraceEEE + 452
        19  libtensorflow_cc.2.dylib            0x00000002a0b4282c _ZN10tensorflow11ExecuteNode3RunEv + 396
        20  libtensorflow_cc.2.dylib            0x00000002a0b829f4 _ZN10tensorflow13EagerExecutor11SyncExecuteEPNS_9EagerNodeE + 244
        21  libtensorflow_cc.2.dylib            0x00000002a0b37aa4 _ZN10tensorflow12_GLOBAL__N_117EagerLocalExecuteEPNS_14EagerOperationEPPNS_12TensorHandleEPi + 2580
        22  libtensorflow_cc.2.dylib            0x00000002a0b35784 _ZN10tensorflow14DoEagerExecuteEPNS_14EagerOperationEPPNS_12TensorHandleEPi + 416
        23  libtensorflow_cc.2.dylib            0x00000002a0b351c4 _ZN10tensorflow14EagerOperation7ExecuteEN4absl12lts_202301254SpanIPNS_20AbstractTensorHandleEEEPi + 132
        24  libtensorflow_cc.2.dylib            0x00000002a0b81744 _ZN10tensorflow21CustomDeviceOpHandler7ExecuteEPNS_27ImmediateExecutionOperationEPPNS_30ImmediateExecutionTensorHandleEPi + 572
        25  libtensorflow_cc.2.dylib            0x00000002a7497b00 TFE_Execute + 80
        26  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x000000010429400c _Z24TFE_Py_FastPathExecute_CP7_object + 12808
        27  _pywrap_tfe.so                      0x0000000108ce919c _ZZN8pybind1112cpp_function10initializeIZL25pybind11_init__pywrap_tfeRNS_7module_EE4$_63NS_6objectEJNS_4argsEEJNS_4nameENS_5scopeENS_7siblingEEEEvOT_PFT0_DpT1_EDpRKT2_ENUlRNS_6detail13function_callEE_8__invokeESN_ + 68
        28  _pywrap_tfe.so                      0x0000000108cc517c _ZN8pybind1112cpp_function10dispatcherEP7_objectS2_S2_ + 3552
        29  Python                              0x0000000103522578 cfunction_call + 60
        30  Python                              0x00000001034be568 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 128
        31  Python                              0x00000001035e1968 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 53908
        32  Python                              0x00000001035e7020 _PyEval_Vector + 156
        33  Python                              0x00000001034be8f8 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 208
        34  Python                              0x000000010354b488 slot_tp_init + 180
        35  Python                              0x0000000103541fa0 type_call + 136
        36  Python                              0x00000001034be568 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 128
        37  Python                              0x00000001035e1968 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 53908
        38  Python                              0x00000001035d3448 PyEval_EvalCode + 276
        39  Python                              0x000000010364c574 pyrun_file + 240
        40  Python                              0x000000010364bd44 _PyRun_SimpleFileObject + 288
        41  Python                              0x000000010364b2b8 _PyRun_AnyFileObject + 232
        42  Python                              0x000000010367494c pymain_run_file_obj + 220
        43  Python                              0x0000000103674130 pymain_run_file + 72
        44  Python                              0x0000000103673944 Py_RunMain + 1828
        45  Python                              0x0000000103674ac8 pymain_main + 52
        46  Python                              0x0000000103675300 Py_BytesMain + 40
        47  dyld                                0x00000001024dd0f4 start + 520
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
zsh: abort      python3 food101_big_dog.py
(/Users/ambroseling/Desktop/tensorflow-env/env) a
```

Would anyone happen to understand why this is happening? Would I have to install an older version of tensorflow-macos? Because when I tried installing an older version it doesn't seem to be available

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-macos==2.11.0 (from versions: 2.12.0, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-macos==2.11.0
```

Any help on this would be really appreciated thank you.